# How do you taint resources on Atlas

Tags: terraform

I'm just getting started with Terraform and I'm looking to taint resources with [Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com) and I don't see an obvious way to do that. Do I need to do that from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Cameron Stokes of Hashicorp, there is no way to taint resources in Atlas currently. You instead have to change the configuration such that the resource gets re-created and then run plan & apply on that resource.